# Exceptions in constructor

Tags: c#

I need someone to tell me what the meaning of this image:

[image]

I tried to understand it and I created some test code. I added a `try`, `catch`, and `finally` blocks to a constructor and it worked very well!

So what is wrong?

(Source code I tried: just a test)

```
class Numbers
{
    public Numbers()
    {
        try
        {
            int[] array = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                array[i] = i;
                // here obviously an IndexOutOfRangeException will be thrown.
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop is looping 10 times, but your int[] can only hold 6 ints ( counting from index 0 )

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Of course the code works as written. But does this help you? It's just almost never the right choice.

Comment: What is the source, is it even credible? Either way: the question is opinion based.

Comment: Btw, in the current JIT the exception will be thrown before the first loop iteration. That's a miscompilation. This is intentional as per MS Connect. RyuJIT fixes this.

Comment: What's wrong is that you're swallowing the exception instead of actually fixing the root cause.  Sweeping the problem under the rug is even *worse* than not actually fixing it.

Comment: @usr: [Citation needed]  Or is it a non-public Connect issue?

Comment: @BenVoigt I tested it yesterday (coincidentally) with both JITs. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817155/jit-bug-in-net-4-0-2-x64 I'm not the first one to have discovered this.

Comment: If a constructor throws an exception, it's up to the client what to do about it, nothing automagically handles the exception by keeping a null reference and continuing as if nothing has happened. If a constructor catches and handles an exception, the client absolutely ends up with an instance of the class. Why don't you show us the context of what this image is talking about?

Comment: @Patrick, why did you edit out the user's code?  That doesn't seem remotely helpful to anyone.

Comment: Why do people not bother filling out the bug report completely, resulting in valid problems getting ignored?!?

Comment: @KirkWoll: The first comments (some deleted already) were solely about the example. The question is good enough without it.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I reverted to my edited question (fixed a lot of typos), and included the source code at the end making clear it was an attempt.

Comment: @BenVoigt what do you mean? Is this statement related to the Connect item? It seems like they understand but won't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip says that it's *highly desirable* to not write any kind of code inside a constructor that can produce an exception, cause that potentially can lead to a confusion inside code, difficulties in consuming your type and as this is not a common practice (avoiding that kind of code is most cases is fairly easy), the consumer of your type will not *expect* that kind of behavior from this instance.

Even in your case, playing an evil here, I can say that your `try/catch/finally` does not cover all possible cases, as exception like `StackOverflow`, or `MemoryOverflow` can not be caught.

Comment: Throwing exceptions in a constructor is not bad practice. ["Do throw exceptions from instance constructors if appropriate.

Constructors should throw and handle exceptions like any method. Specifically, a constructor should not catch and hide any exceptions that it cannot handle."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The behavior is entirely predicable.  It may be annoying to some people, but it's predictable.

Comment: @Servy: the point here is that exception happens in exceptional cases, and if one uses an exception for orchestrating running code, using them inside a ctor, is a sign of a bad architecture. so leaving aside a second case, the first leads to unpredictable behavior of the application.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: this is kind of topic of "like" or "don't like". I personally hate that kind of code inside constructor, and my personal suggesion to OP, is to avoid writing code like that in any possible way. In most cases, it's fairly easy to do.

Comment: @Tigran Stating that it causes unpredictable behavior is to imply that you won't know what will happen to the program when an exception is thrown.  That's not true.  The programmer may not expect the constructor to throw, and may write code with that assumption, but it's certainly predicable behavior, and the effects of throwing in a constructor are very well defined.  That some people don't predict it doesn't make it "unpredictable".

Comment: @Tigran: a constructor has to handle bad input in the same way as properties or methods, so why should it avoid to fail fast with a meaningful expection? Actually it makes your code more robust and predictable.

Comment: @Servy: understand your point. changed my answer to more accurate description (hope so)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: *in my opinion* the constructor is for constructing of the object, so it *shouldn't* handle non correct inputs. Repeat, this is something that, in my opinion, is highly desirable. Sure there are cases when handling invalid input in ctor is most neat way. At the end, the question OP asks is about a tip he read. So my answer describes reasoning behind that, and justifications for it. Non dogma..

Comment: @Tigran As others are saying, there's nothing wrong in throwing an exception in the constructor in C# - in fact, it's the preferred way of signaling construction problems, rather than using status values, etc.

Comment: @Tigran Your answer would be valid for C++ but in C#, a constructor throwing an exception is not at all unexpected - calling code should be ready to deal with exceptions at any time.

Comment: @xxbbcc: there is nothing wrong, yes. but it's not desirable.

Comment: @Tigran: yes, but imho it's better to throw the exception instead of initializing an object half or incorrectly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: agree, where it is appropriate. but wouldn't suggest that as widely used practice, to be honest. handling IO ? ok. handling remote connections? OK.. but not in coping arrays, or something else. make a separate method for that. repeat, I'm not talking all possible solutions, just answering *this concrete question*.

Comment: @Tigran I disagree with you - it's most certainly desirable to throw an exception in C# constructors if the object cannot be constructed without problems. Otherwise you'd construct a bad instance and some properties would have be checked by the caller to detect problems. That's very problematic.

Comment: @Tigran, I am genuinely curious what you'd expect the proper behavior of `new StringBuilder(-1)` to be.  (Currently it, IMO, properly throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`)  There are countless similar examples.  In fact, the assertion in the "tip", that the "statement that tried to instantiate the class won't end up with an instance of the object" is spurious at best -- since that statement will never complete in the first place due to the thrown exception.

Comment: Throwing an exception in a constructor is perfectly valid if you don't want the instance to be created in an invalid state. Often used in DDD where you don't want invalid domain entities to be created.